# Not able to mount VHD drive on azure server

Tags: c#, azure

Please help me. I am writing following code to mount the vhd file. But I am not able to mount it. It works fine locally but when I deploy it on azure server the webrole remains offline. I tried by removing foreach block below but in vain. But when I removed the code "Global.driveLetter = drive.Mount(localCache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes - 20, DriveMountOptions.Force);" role got ready on server. But I can't do this because this is the key statement to mount the drive.

What would be the problem?

```
    private static void MountAzureDrive()
    {
        string connectionStringSettingName = "AzureConnectionString";
        string azureDriveContainerName = "azuredrives";
        string azureDrivePageBlobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToLowerInvariant();
        string azureDriveCacheDirName = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "cache");

        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((a, b) =>
        {
            b(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(connectionStringSettingName));
        });

        //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount=CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting(connectionStringSettingName);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount=CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;

        LocalResource localCache=RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("InstanceDriveCache");
        CloudDrive.InitializeCache(localCache.RootPath + "cache", localCache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes);

        // Just checking: make sure the container exists
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        blobClient.GetContainerReference("drives").CreateIfNotExist();

        // Create cloud drive
     //WebRole.drive=storageAccount.CreateCloudDrive(blobClient.GetContainerReference("drives").GetPageBlobReference("Test.VHD").Uri.ToString());
        WebRole.drive = storageAccount.CreateCloudDrive("drives/Test.VHD");

        try
        {
            WebRole.drive.CreateIfNotExist(512);
        }
        catch (CloudDriveException ex)
        {
            // handle exception here
            // exception is also thrown if all is well but the drive already exists
        }

        foreach (var d in CloudDrive.GetMountedDrives())
        {
            var mountedDrive = storageAccount.CreateCloudDrive(d.Value.PathAndQuery);
            mountedDrive.Unmount();
        }
        //Global.driveLetter = drive.Mount(25, DriveMountOptions.Force);
        Global.driveLetter = drive.Mount(localCache.MaximumSizeInMegabytes - 20, DriveMountOptions.Force);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try putting the whole thing in a try/catch and see if something is happening.  Or log into the instance and debug it.  If you have VS Ultimate, use IntelliTrace.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is stating the obvious, but... when you deploy to Windows Azure, did you change the storage account from dev storage? You have the dev storage emulator hard-coded:

`CloudStorageAccount storageAccount=CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;`